# Why does Rust forbid implementations of existing types?

Tags: methods, types, rust, implementation

How is this...

```
impl String {
    fn foo(&self) {
        //...
    }
}
```

...any different to this?

```
fn foo(s: &String) {
    //...
}
```

Then again, it is possible to extend the type implementation if you define a trait in your crate. Why?

Comment: Relevent RFC: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/493. More specifically you might want to jump to this part of the discussion: https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/493#issuecomment-266307203

Comment: @asteriskTheServer: This sounds like a good answer in a comment. Why don't you try massaging it in a proper answer that uses the comment as source?

Comment: There seems to be a visibility problem here; how would you expect visibility of `String::foo` to be controlled? Traits support adding new methods: `trait Foo { fn foo(&self); } impl Foo for String { ... }`. Here visibility of `String::foo` can be controlled by importing the trait, and different traits implementing `foo` can be disambiguated using the full trait name.

Comment: @user4815162342 But why not allow private implementations then?

Comment: I just re-read the RFC you posted @asteriskTheServer and I think I got it now. Public impls would expose the changes to other crates and local impls would override future patches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different arguments as indicated by the following [source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/493) as to why one is unable to implement existing types that are outside of one's crate.

- Local impl can be broken by future implementations. For example, consider "you've locally defined Add on `Vec<T>` as a concat operator, ... , and then ... after years of debate ... some mathy operation [is] to be performed instead. If you delete your impl and upgrade, your code will be ... broken<sup>[2](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/493#issuecomment-266705533)</sup>."
- The readability of the code will also be affected by this change, that is, it could make the "value of that reading far more transient<sup>[3](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/493#issuecomment-266744882)</sup>."
- There is also a security concern. Consider the following scenario that would be technically possible if this were allowed, that is, "an attacker [could] find a change in an impl in [some] library, a call site in an application they wish to backdoor, and send a "refactoring" pull request that "accidentally" replaces the new impl with the old impl so as to create a vulnerability, but their pull can reference the old code from the library. And they can embed the hostile impl into a macro in yet another create<sup>[4](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/493#issuecomment-266744882)</sup>."
- Assuming the case that the local impl would be the preferred implementation if local impls were allowed. This would "would violate the coherence property [that is currently being maintained]<sup>[5](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/493#issuecomment-283289586)</sup>." This point can be further clarified through what is called the 'HashTable' problem<sup>[5](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/493#issuecomment-283289586)</sup>.

  ```
  mod foo {
      impl Hash for i32 { ... }

      fn f(mut table: HashMap<i32, &'static str>) {
          table.insert(0, "hello");
          ::bar::f(&table);
      }
  }

  mod bar {
      impl Hash for i32 { ... }

      fn f(table: &HashMap<i32, &'static str>) {
          assert_eq!(table.get(0), Some("hello"));
      }
  }
  ```